# How to get pod volume list using python?

Tags: python, kubernetes

My pod has a volume as:

```json
        "volumes": [
            {
                "name": "configs",
                "secret": {
                    "defaultMode": 420,
                    "secretName": "some_secret"
                }
            },
            ....]
```

I want to be able to read it using Python as `V1Volume`.

Tried to do:

```py
    from kubernetes import config
    config.load_incluster_config()
    spec = client.V1PodSpec()
```

But I'm stuck as it gives me

```py
    raise ValueError("Invalid value for `containers`, must not be `None`")
```

and I'm not sure how to continue. How can I get the volumes from the `V1PodSpec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives you the error because you initialise `V1PodSpec` without any arguments. `V1PodSpec` used to create pods, not to read them.

To read pod `spec` from Kubernetes:

```py
from  kubernetes import client,config
config.load_kube_config()
# or 
# config.load_incluster_config()
core_api = client.CoreV1Api()
response = core_api.read_namespaced_pod(name="debug-pod", namespace='dev')

# access volumes in the returned response
type(response.spec.volumes[0])
# returns:
# <class 'kubernetes.client.models.v1_volume.V1Volume'>
```

Comment: But I don't want to create a pod... I want to get information from existed pod. When I run `kubectl get pods -n my_name_space my_worker_pod -o json | less` I can see the pod configuration. I want to get at least that using Python code (or if possible get directly the V1Volume)

Comment: @sony You should have put that into the question. Check the updated section in the answer.

Comment: thx. is there a way to get the volumes as `V1Volume` ?

Comment: @sony it returns volumes as `V1Volume` by default. `type(core_api.read_namespaced_pod(name="debug-pod", namespace='dev').spec.volumes[0])`

Comment: can you help me how to replace the [0] with name so it will be more readable?

Comment: @sony `.spec.volumes` is a list of volumes, `[0]` - is the first element of it. Use `print` on each instead of `type` which I gave as an example. Also, volume name is available at `response.spec.volumes[0].name`.